# Finding files older than X hours using Ruby

Tags: ruby, shell

I am in the middle of migrating all my bash scripts to Ruby. I am finding Ruby to be awesome however am stuck with a small problem. I am trying to move this script (basically find all logs older than x hours and process them).  The Bash script looks something like this

```
find /var/log/myservice.log.* -mmin -120  -exec cp {} /home/myhomedir/mylogs/ \;
```

Of course I can loop through all the files, manually apply `File.mtime` on them and then identify the ones. However I want to understand if there is a much cleaner, one-liner to do this efficiently.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One liner:

```
require 'fileutils'; Dir.glob("/var/log/myservice.log.*").each{|f| FileUtils.cp(f, '/home/myhomedir/mylogs/') if File.mtime(f) < (Time.now - (60*120)) }
```

Though I would prefer it spelled out a bit more:

```
require 'fileutils'
Dir.glob("/var/log/myservice.log.*").
  select{|f| File.mtime(f) < (Time.now - (60*120)) }.
  each{|f| FileUtils.cp(f, '/home/myhomedir/mylogs/') }
```

Comment: Pretty much what i was thinking. The method chaining looks cool though

Comment: How about (Time.now - 2.hours) ?

Comment: @Roger `2.hours` is provided in Rails by requiring `activesupport`. This question did not mention Rails, so I provided a pure Ruby solution.

Comment: @Unixmonkey oops. Damn. Sorry. Didn’t realize that. Good point.